# Storing data on the harddrive or other flash drives from a bootable USB Stick

Tags: usb, live-usb

we are looking at options for deploying some simple software to hundreds of enrollment centres.

We are thinking of using bootable USB sticks. However, we would need to take backups.

So the question is, is it possible to save to other drives from ubuntu bootable USB sticks?

Best,

Ajay

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Yes, it is possible to save to another drive from the Ubuntu LiveUSB, all you have to do is have the file on the LiveUSB and then mount the drive you wish to save to. Navigate to the place where you want to store the file on the newly mounted drive and then you place the file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Yes, it is possible to save to another drive from the Ubuntu LiveUSB, all you have to do is have the file on the LiveUSB and then mount the drive you wish to save to. Navigate to the place where you want to store the file on the newly mounted drive and then you place the file there.

How to:

1. Start the file manager.
2. Look up the upper-left-hand corner. There should be a label saying `Devices`. Your drive should show up there.
3. Click on the drive you want to store the file in. It should be already mounted, but if not it will mount it for you.
4. Navigate to the folder on the drive and place the file as you want. All done!